# How can I paginate in descending order by child value with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have some data as follows:

```
{
    "name": "post #1",
    "votes": 100
},
{
    "name": "post #2",
    "votes": 10000
},
{
    "name": "post #3",
    "votes": 750
}
```

And so on.

The data in firebase is not ordered by votes obviously, it's order by key.

I'd like to be able to paginate this data by the number of votes **in descending order.**

I think I'd have to do something like:

```
ref.orderByChild('votes')
    .startAt(someValue)
    .limitToFirst(someOtherValue)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
        resolve(snapshot);
    });
```

Or perhaps, I'd need to use `limitToLast`, and `endAt`?

Pagination by `key` is quite easy, but this one is stumping me.

**Update (2017-10-16):** Firebase recently announced [Firestore](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/introducing-cloud-firestore.html) - their fully managed NoSQL datastore which should make it easier to do more complex queries. There may still be some use cases where one might use the Realtime database they've always provided. If you're one of those people this question should still apply.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195851/how-to-retrieve-paginated-children-in-ascending-or-descending-order-in-firebase/33484784#33484784

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Your link is to a question which then links back to my answer below. Might you guys consider adding this information to the Firebase docs?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I posted this question after a long day of coding and my brain was mush.

I took another crack at it this morning, and as is so often the case, was able to find the solution rather quickly.

**Solution:**

In order to paginate data, we need the ability to arbitrarily pull sorted data from the middle of a list. You can do this using the following functions provided by the firebase API:

`startAt`

`endAt`

`limitToFirst`

`limitToLast`

More information can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#methods).

In my case, since I need my data in descending order, I'll use `endAt` and `limitToLast`.

Assuming I'd like each of my pages to have **five** items. I would write my first query like so:

```
ref.orderByChild('votes')
    .limitToLast(5)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log('Snap: ', snapshot.val());
    });
```

This gets the 5 items with the **highest** number of votes.

In order to get the next page, we'll need to store **two** pieces of data from the results of our last query. We need to store the number of votes, and key for the item that had the least number of votes. That is to say, the last item in our list.

Using that data, our next query, and all subsequent queries, would look as follows:

```
ref.orderByChild('votes')
    .endAt(previousVoteCount, previousKey)
    .limitToLast(5)
    .once('value', function(snapshot) {
      console.log('Snap: ', snapshot.val());
    });
```

You'll notice in this query I added `endAt`. This gets the next 5 items with the most votes starting from the last one in the previous list. We must include the the key for the last item in the previous list so that if there are multiple items with the same number of votes, it'll return a list beginning with the correct item, and not the first one it finds with that number of votes, which could be somewhere in the middle of the list you got from the initial query.

That's it!

Comment: Is this solution works with many same-value items? For example following scores: [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]. In a real world scenario, not many high-voted post will share the same value, but a LOT of low-score values will. This issue is commented in my SO question highlighted by @frank-van-puffelen above.

Comment: Assuming you're storing your data in a single list with firebase keys then the  orderByChild part of the query will sort by 'votes' first, then should there be many posts with the same number of votes, it'll sort by key.

Comment: So that means, if you include the 'previousKey' argument in the 'endAt' part of the query, you'll be able to paginate accurately.

Comment: AH - yes... with the key indeed :-) I always thought `endAt()` only took one parameter, the value. Makes sense, i'll update my other post!

Comment: @Tyler thank you very much for this solution +1. i only had one question , what if i wanted to do your solution but i need to specify another key value , for example we added type to your data scheme , { "name","vote" , "type"} and i want type=3  , is there a way to apply your pagenation solution and add type =3 . ?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that using the Firebase SDK. In my experience using firebase, the solution to your problem would be to change the way you're storing your data. So instead of having one long flat list that contains all item types, you'd split the list up by item type and paginate off of each branch? Does that make sense? Take a look at this gist if it isn't clear: https://gist.github.com/biscoe916/59b9dbd00a0a92e19698a9df9beb85f7

Comment: In some cases, when coming to firebase or other nosql datastores, you sort of need to rethink the way you store data.

Comment: But how to add this newly retrived data to the bottom of the recylerview

Comment: @TylerBiscoe Thanks for the thorough explanation. The only question I have is if you pull the last 5 results, won't they still come back in ascending order? (because orderByChild returns in ascending order). I have read that it is still required to do reverse ordering on the client, unless you do a negative timestamp on Firebase. Thanks for reading!