# Load more data retrieving from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app, that let user syncing data from Firebase database. When the app starts up 10 records load into Listview, when the user scrolls down listview I want to load 10 items more.
Could you give me suggestion to do that ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+pagination

Comment: Thank Frank. I got the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38024909/5856328