# Firebase how to sort collection via createdAt field?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection model that looks like this :

[image]

How do I sort the query from latest to oldest via the `createdAt` field.

So far I tried

```
db.ref('accounts')
    .startAt()
    .orderByChild('createdAt')
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snap){
        // do shits here...
    })
```

But am getting the data the oldest on top.

1. January
2. February
3. March

But I want

1. March
2. February
3. January

Comment: you can reverse your list after getting  but it's better to get reversed from firebase http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963075/3496570  or http://stackoverflow.com/a/10766502/3496570

Comment: Those are java solutions, well anyways thanks for the idea :) @Nepster

Comment: try limitToLast like  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33484784/3496570 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/38024909/3496570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no method to get items sorted in descending order in firebase database. So you need to sort them by ascending and reverse the array in your programming language.
2. If you want to sort them by time you should be using timestamp instead of datetime as string. In this case you will get wrong ordering because they are actually compared as strings. For example: Imagine this two dates `2016-10-14T02:30:59.653Z`, `2016-10-2T02:30:59.653Z`. As dates first one is greater but as a strings (lexicographically) second one is greater.

Comment: !!!!welcome!!!!

Comment: @Zura: It looks like the times are in ISO-8601 format, which requires leading zeros, specifically to ensure that the strings can be lexicographically ordered.

Comment: Hello, i know theres been lots of time but, this is working correctly on me ?